# Error #1009 após a primeira execução

Tags: actionscript-3

Sou iniciante no AS3, e estou construindo um jogo para um curso que estou fazendo.

Como quero que o jogo fique bem caprichado, resolvi criar um jogo com menu, onde você pode acessar as preferências básicas (Desligar música, instruções, etc.)

E quando abro o jogo, e aperto o botão para iniciar, ele funciona normalmente, como foi programado, e não demonstra nenhum tipo de erro no console.

meu problema é o jogo insiste em me demonstrar o `Error #1009` APÓS a primeira execução!

Vale ressaltar que, quando a pessoa perde no jogo, ela recebe dois botões: Um lhe permite um reinício rápido ao jogo (voltando ao frame 1 da cena), e outro leva de volta ao menu principal, se a pessoa retorna ao jogo imediatamente, ele funciona sem problemas novamente. Esse bug só acontece quando a pessoa perde, volta ao menu, e só então volta a jogar!

Para entender o que estava causando o problema, permiti a depuração, e o resultado:

[image: Saída]

Fui verificar o código na linha 2 e percebi que nada mais é do que a confirmação de que o jogador ainda possui vidas:

[image: Código]

Vale ressaltar a variável `lives` na timeline principal:

[image: Variável lives]

Imagino que, por se tratar de um teste do valor da variável `int`, não deveria ser entendido como objeto pelo AS3, muito menos um objeto nulo, mas sou novo no AS3, então não tenho certeza disso!

**EDIT:** Seguindo a dica do Lucas Nunes, acrescentei:

[image: Código2]

Resultado:

[image: Saida2]

Como devo proceder com esse MovieClip(root) quando ele se tornar nulo??

Comment: Será que não foi a conversão de `MovieClip(root)` que falhou? Verifique se `MovieClip(root) != null` antes do resto de `controlShield()` para a gente ver...

Comment: Realmente foi o MovieClip(root) que falhou! Como devo proceder??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu não sei exatamente como você está estruturando seu projeto, mas pelo que parece você não está utilizando bem o conceito de Objetos do Flash.

O ideal é que você define uma classe que presente o objeto. Por exemplo:

```
package
{   
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent; 

    public class Caixa extends MovieClip 
    {
        // atributos...
        private var foo:int = 0;

        public function Caixa()
        {
            // seu codigo do contrutor
        }

        public function sumir() : void
        {
            this.visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

E, no Flash, associe o `MovieClip` a essa classe (quando for criar um ou nas propriedades dele):

[image: Associando a Classe]

Depois disso você pode fazer o que está querendo. Vamos supor que você tenha um `MovieClip` (que é do tipo Caixa) que se chama obj_caixa no `stage`, você pode fazer, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

obj_caixa.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, destruirCaixa);

function destruirCaixa(e:MouseEvent) : void
{
    obj_caixa.sumir();
}
```

Ou pode definir o `addEventListener` dentro da classe (dependendo do que você quer fazer).
Nesse exemplo, o que você chama de `MovieClip(root)` é que o eu chamei de `obj_caixa`.